# jQuery validate: number vs digits

Tags: jquery-validate

I wonder, what is the difference between `number` and `digits` methods? I have been working with this plugin for a long time, and both of these methods seem to return the same result...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Number rule will accept decimal numbers where as Digits won't accept decimals instead only digits.

**Number**

```
12.1 // true
-4   // true
```

**Digits**

```
12.1 // false
-4   // false
```

Check these samples :[Digits](http://jqueryvalidation.org/digits-method/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Plugins/Validation/Methods/digits&redirect=no)

and  [Number](http://jqueryvalidation.org/number-method/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Plugins/Validation/Methods/number&redirect=no)

Comment: So a digit is a whole number only?
Will 3 be a digit and a number? 12.1 is a number, but not a digit?